# EasyMock Expect Field Value is Null

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, easymock

I am new to EasyMock, usually use Mockito, so please excuse this if it is a stupid question, but I have an expect call that uses one of the fields from the class I am testing. The problem is that since execute is ran before the actually method call, the field is null.

```
public class ClassToTest {
    SomeObject someObject = null;
    AnotherObject anotherObject;

    public String testMethod() {
        someObject = new SomeObject();
        String result = anotherObject.someMethod(someObject);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    // Some other code here
}
```

`ClassToTest testClass = new ClassToTest();
AnotherObject mockedObject = createMock(AnotherObject.class);
expect(mockedObject.someMethod(testClass.someObject)).andStubReturn("test");
testClass.testMethod();`

In Mockito this would be written as
`when(mockObject.someMethod(testClass.someObject)).thenReturn("test");`
and whatever someObject is at that point in execution would be used. However, using EasyMock, since someObject is null at the time that the expect call is set up, the call expects null as a parameter.

Is there a way in EasyMock to instead get whatever the field is at the point in the code when someMethod is actually called?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand where `foo` came from - is it something that you've captured previously?

Comment: Indeed - it would be a lot easier to understand with a short but *complete* example.

Comment: I updated with some code, very rough sketch of the logic scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do what you described with EasyMock.

Here are some alternatives:

**1)**

If you want to accept any object of a type, then you can use EasyMock.anyObject(SomeClass.class) as a method parameter

```
expect(mockedObject.someMethod(EasyMock.anyObject(SomeClass.class)).andReturn("test")
```

**2)**

You can mock the constructor of SomeObject using PowerMock (https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor) and then expect the object you returned when mocking the constructor. It would look something like this

```
SomeObject myObject = new SomeObject()
PowerMock.expectNew(SomeObject.class).andReturn(myObject);
expect(mockedObject.someMethod(myObject)).andReturn("test");
```

If you go the PowerMock route, do check out that link as there are some extra lines of codes that are required when using PowerMock.

Comment: Think #2 is the solution as I need to do this for multiple specific instances. Thanks!